# Fastest geolocation (IP to town)?

Tags: php, geolocation

I am writing small geolocation service: then user come to my site I should to set his town from his IP-address. Now I found three way to solve this problem:

1. Create from PHP connection to MySql DB and select town from it.
2. From PHP go to cgi script (perl,c ?) and select town from file with towns and IP-addrs.
3. Use services like http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php and get town from it.

But what way would be fastest? Minimal time etc?

Thanks!

Comment: 4. ngx_http_geo_module is the fastest one for sure

Comment: please make it as answer and mbe I mark your answer as correct :)

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: could you explain why instead of just stating "for sure"?

Comment: @Erno nope. it's boring. Ones who run this web-server, do know the answer already.  And ones who don't, do not need the answer at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy answer to it because a lot depends on unknown factors such as:

1. Speed of your MySQL DB
2. Speed of your php inplementation and size of the file
3. Speed of the location_api service

In other words, there are only two ways to find out the answer:

1. build them all and test
2. gather all parameters (speeds, bandwidth, concurrent users of all systems) and calculate/guesstimate.

Comment: thx. But how usally solve this problem other developers?

Comment: What do you mean? You ask which one is better/faster, I tell you it depends on many factors that are missing from your question and how to find out yourself. How could other programmers tell you what to do without knowing all your parameters?

Comment: I thought what some standarts already exist for this. Your answer is right but for me interesting some services and technologies like ngx_http_geo_module.

Comment: OK, if that is what you are after you should state that in your question.

Answer (score 2):

3.

Primarily because of just how much data you'd have to manually compile together to do either 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [MaxMind](http://maxmind.com/) database for country-level lookup from PHP (there is example code for other languages). The downloadable database is in a binary format optimised for speed of reading - although I've not compared it to a import into Mysql and searching with SQL, I have no doubt of Maxmind when they say it would be faster to use the API and original data rather than via another means, like SQL.